# Intellij IDEA HTTP Client - How can i save variable from response body

Tags: json, http, intellij-plugin

In JetBrains Doc says, that you can save a variable of response body to global variables:

```
//Saving a variable
> {%
    client.global.set("auth_token", response.body.json.token);
%}
```

But in my IDE there is an error "Unresolved variable json" on statement ".json.token":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvAm.png)

Can enyone help me? Is there possability of saving valiables values from request body to global variables for using them in next requests of the same http file at all?

Answer (score 3):

Try access token variable (without the `.json` part) doing this instead:

```
> {%
    client.global.set("auth_token", response.body.token);
%}
```

And then, you can access that variable doing this:

```
{{auth_token}}
```